# Parrot os issue

Tags: linux, debian, gnu, parrot-os

I have problem with parrot secuirity os ihave upgrade it from parrot 4.18 to parrot 4.4 when i login with my true login and password the root account or the parrot user account a black screen appears and the login form pup up again if i put a wrong identifier and password it tell me "wrong user name or password " i tryed the ctrl +alt +f1 it and try to login it tells me that the user or pass are wrong all the time i try a pass im tiered i tryed user:toor parrot:toor root:root and a nother big list of logins but no ruslt please help

Comment: Hi Evgueni, welcome to SO. Unfortunately I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming, and belongs to e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions or https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux#

Answer (score 1):

Boot off of Parrot live, mount the drive and blank out the password in /etc/shadow (or set it to a known value).